# Code not working after if clause

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to network programming and wrote a chat client. It's almost working, but when I add the if clause suddenly `in.hasnext` returns false even when my server actually sends something.

With if clause:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    while(!server.isClosed()){


        if(ChatClient.WriteListener.message!=null){
            String m = ChatClient.WriteListener.message;
            out.println(m);
            ChatClient.WriteListener.message = null;
        }

        if(in.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("hab");
            String message = in.next();
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"\n"+message.replaceAll("_", " "));
        }
        out.flush();
    }
    System.out.println("closed");

}
```

Without if clause

```
public void run() {
    while(!server.isClosed()){          
        out.println(ChatClient.WriteListener.message);      
        if(in.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("hab");
            String message = in.next();
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"\n"+message.replaceAll("_", " "));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("closed");

}
```

Creation of in and out:

```
    public UserThread(Socket s){
    server = s;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter( server.getOutputStream(), true );
        in  = new Scanner( server.getInputStream() );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

WriteListener

```
public static class WriteListener implements ActionListener {
    JTextField text;
    static String message;
    public WriteListener(JTextField jtf){
        text = jtf;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {       
        message = text.getText();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `ChatClient.WriteListener.message = null;` Why did you do this?

Comment: what is `in`?  How is it created?

Comment: please add code for creation of `in` and `out`

Comment: @Zircon so it wont be sent again

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is here:

```
if (ChatClient.WriteListener.message!=null){
        String m = ChatClient.WriteListener.message;
        out.println(m);
        ChatClient.WriteListener.message = null;
}
```

Your `out` is of instance `PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`. When you call `out.println(m)` in the first `if` statement `PrintWriter` flushes buffer/stream on the Socket resulting in your second `if(in.hasNext())` statement returning `false` because your I/O from socket was auto closed by `PrintWriter`. You need to change/remove `true` from the initialization of the `PrintWriter` as follows :

```
try {
    out = new PrintWriter( server.getOutputStream());
    in  = new Scanner( server.getInputStream() );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JavaDoc: [PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Have you changed the argument to false rather than just removing the argument?

Comment: When you saying that "it worked without the if clause" it clearly indicates that you are doing something in the if statement that changes/closes the stream from the socket. Only thing that is there is that's doing something is `out.println(m)` so that's probably the problem unless your `WriteListener` contains some logic. My best guess is that you are closing socket connection before you try to access input stream so your `in` stream is empty. Try removing `out.println(m)` statement and see if it works. If so that's the problem as I assumed. Try using different output than `PrintWriter`

Comment: @MichaelDD I mean it does work if i dont check if ChatClient.WriteListener.message!=null if i you look my code without if clause in my question it works

Comment: sounds stupid i know and im just sitting here thinking wtf

Comment: Add code for `WriteListener` inside `ChatClient` so we can have a look to see if there's some logic inside the listener that might closing the stream

Comment: @MichaelDD its there

Comment: Ok I can't help you any further as that was the only thing that came to my mind. Wait for others if they come up with something